# Radiobuttons and checkbox values

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I want to make a "calculator" thing with radiobuttons and checkboxes.
When a radiobutton is checked this must happen:
1. Checkbox above will be automatically checked when the radiobutton is checked.
2. All radiobuttons have values. If the radiobuttons are checked, the values will be added together.
3. this must be javascript (not jQuery)

Here is my html code:

```
     <form name="CalorieForm">
    <input type="checkbox"> Groente en fruit <br />
      <ul><input type="radio"> Appel (60 kcal per appel) <br />
      <input type="radio"> Paprika (60 kcal per paprika) <br /></ul>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox"> Brood, pasta en peelvruchten <br />
      <ul><input type="radio"> Zilvervliesrijst (111 kcal per 100 gram) <br />
      <input type="radio"> Sperziebonen(24 kcal per 100 gram)<br /></ul>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox"> Zuivel, vlees, vis, ei en vleesvervangers <br />
      <ul><input type="radio"> Kabeljauwfilet (118 kcal per 100 gram) <br />
      <input type="radio"> Biefstuk (115 kcal per 100 gram) <br /></ul>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox"> Vetten en olie <br />
      <ul><input type="radio"> Olie (108 kcal per eetlepel) <br />
      <input type="radio"> Halvarine (90 kcal per 25 gram) <br /></ul>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox"> Vocht <br />
      <ul><input type="radio"> Thee (0 kcal per 0.5 liter) <br />
      <input type="radio"> Coca cola light (0.6 kcal per blikje) <br /></ul>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Bereken de calorieën" onClick="BerekeningCalorie()"> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    <br>
    <br>
    Aantal calorieën: <input type="text" name="Calorie" size="20"><br />
 </form>
```

Comment: Something unrelated to your question...you're using an ordered list, but the items that you add in aren't list items. Wrap the items in <li>, else the <ul> has no effect ;)

Comment: What is your question? We are not going to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the click event on the radio button (onClick="javascriptFunction()") and then execute javascript code from that function. This allows you to execute that code every time the radio button is clicked.

From there you can do both the things you want to do.

To select the checkboxes, you will need to give the checkboxes an ID or something to identify them by. Then you can select the ID using document.getElementById(elementId) and apply the javascript to it. There's plenty of documentation on making checkboxes selected, so you can google that yourself.

Adding the value means you simply have to retrieve the value of the current radio button and add it to a variable. Again, you can find this on the internet.